# Nodejs server with websocket not working remotely

Tags: node.js, websocket

Hello people l have a problem with my nodejs server, l am running a javascript server on debian
and localy works perfect, the problem beggins when l try to call it from outside the local
network, my IP its fixed and and l have installed all l need since it works locally.
Do you know if l need to change something on the server side or in the client side?
My client:

```
socket = new WebSocket ('ws://172.17.31.7:8080', 'proof');
```

My server:

```
wsServer.on('request', function(request)
{
     if ( ! originIsAllowed(request.origin))
     {
           // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin
          request.reject();
          console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
          return;
     }

var con = request.accept('proof', request.origin);
}
```